# Actualizar los valores en una lista

Tags: c#, mvc

Tengo este código, necesito actualizar los valores en caso de que no lo encuentre.

```
List<Rollos> set = new List<Rollos>();

Rollos temp = new Rollos();

foreach (Rollos  y in l)
{
    if (set.Any(x => x.item == y.item))
    {

        temp = set.Where(x => x.item == y.item).Single();
        if (temp != null)
        {
           // set.Where(x => x.item == y.item);

        }
    }

    else {

        set.Add(y);

    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm podrías extraer el indice de tu foreach, para que cuando encuentre lo que buscas, tome el elemento en esa posición y actualice el campo que deseas por ejemplo set[index].Nombre = "Actualizado.". No estoy seguro de si es lo que necesitás, pero espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = l.Where(w => !set.Contains(w)).ToList(); 
set.AddRange(list);
```

Comment: Deberías editar tu respuesta y colocar una breve descripción almenos del código que has colocado.

Comment: soy nuevo usuario, estoy viendo como dar formato al códgo, gracias por la recomendación

Comment: Deberías realizar el [tour] para entender mejor como funciona el sitio.